# Fast Forwarding Videos does not work (HTTP)

Tags: apache-http-server, http, openwrt

I have a router with OpenWRT BB and I have uhttpd as a webserver, which was installed already. Now I have an HTML page with videos, and unfortunately I cannot fast forward the videos on any browser or any device. So the problem is server based.

Maybe the problem is caused by the webserver uhttpd, and I should try a new webserver? Do you have any ideas? It is really confusing.

Comment: @FrankThomas I like your comment but that link is terribly out of date. Since the advent of the iPhone a decade ago, any video streaming website needs to cover HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) the live and on-demand video streaming scheme used by iPhones instead of Flash or QTSS.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, but I do not get what you say. Fast Forwarding does not work on Android as well.

Comment: I was replying to a comment that has since been deleted. I think the real answer for you is to use something like ffmpeg to prep it for HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). That is, break it into smaller files, make a .m3u8, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, uhttp is a problem, you must try nginx webserver. Because I was also facing same problem and now I solved it by nginx.

Comment: Thank you. Installing Nginx instead of uhttpd was the solution. No it works.

Comment: Tick as a right answer then